# Вывести записи с количеством комментов и лайков mysql

Tags: mysql, mysqli

есть таблица статей

```
id title view image
```

таблица комментариев

```
id content_id(id статьи) type(1 статьи) content
```

таблица лайков

```
id content_id(id статьи) type(1 статьи) like
```

пытаюсь вывести список статей с количеством коментариев и лайков для каждого

```
SELECT a.title,a.view,a.id,count(c.id) as comments,SUM(l.like) as raiting FROM `articles` a
left join `comments` c on c.content_id = a.id and c.type = 1
left join `likes` l on l.content_id = a.id and c.type = 1
```

но выводит только одну запись

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

убираю `count(c.id) as comments,SUM(l.like) as raiting`

выводит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: group by a.id ?

Comment: точно, спасибо тебе